# Is there any framework for .NET to populate test data?

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, populate

I am use c# and for unit testing and integration testing usually I need to populate fields automatically based on attributes.  

Lets say we will test if we can write and get back user data to database.

- I create a user object populate fields write user to database
- Read user object from database
- Check fields if what I write is same as what I read

Is there any framework to populate user with test data automatically and check if two object are have the same values?

Sample code may like this

```
User user = new User();
AutoPopulator.Populate(user);
user.Save();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at [NBuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder). It lets you build test objects with random data, incrementing values, and anything you can probably think of. All through a nice fluent interface.

Answer (score 94):

You might find it relevant. Here is a list of few other frameworks as of today:

Well-known and respected:

- [NBuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder)
- [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)
- [AutoPoco](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoPoco/)(Discontinued / Deprecated)
- [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) - C# port of [faker.js](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js) with locale support. Used by Elasticsearch (NEST).

Little-known:

- [Hydrator](http://hydrator.codeplex.com/)
- [Fabricator](http://fabricator.codeplex.com/)

Unfamiliar:

- [TestDataGenerator](https://github.com/etishor/TestDataGenerator)
- [TestDataFactory](https://github.com/titarenko/TestDataFactory) (Discontinued)
- [TestData](https://github.com/worldspawn/TestData)
- [Any-.Net](https://github.com/andrewseward/Any-.Net)

Comment: I could not make AutoPoco work for me but AutoFixture appears to be quite useful.

Comment: Bogus seems to be updated most actively and I quite like its capabilities. Thanks for listing these!

Comment: Bogus worked for me, it works for dotnet core on linux as well which is what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. I found this when watching session #3 of the [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) series by [Stephen Bohlen](http://unhandled-exceptions.com).

His company, [Microdesk](http://www.microdesk.com/), has developed a utility that will allow you to save the state of a database on test fixture construction, set the state of the database at the start of every test, and recover the original state of the database on test fixture deconstruction.

Download the utility here: [Microdesk.Utility.UnitTest](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/09/unittest-utility-library-update/)

For a tutorial on how to use it, watch the Summer of NHibernate session #3 video.

Answer (score -1):

Fluent NHibernate has a feature which gives you everything on your wish-list, except the auto-population part:

Link: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing

However, given C# with code contracts, it wouldn't be to hard to auto-magically create valid objects yourself using reflection.